# Using Custom Color with iOS Charts labelTextColor

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

Does anyone know how to get a custom color to work with labelTextColor in iOS Charts? When I try to plug in a custom color the labels just disappear. For example:

This works:

```
self.chartView.leftAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
```

But something like this does not:

```
self.chartView.rightAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor(red: 150, green: 202, blue: 56, alpha: 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace

```
self.chartView.rightAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor(red: 150, green: 202, blue: 56, alpha: 1)
```

with

```
self.chartView.rightAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor(red: 150.0/255, green: 202.0/255, blue: 56.0/255, alpha: 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I see now that's what the demo meant when it had that. Don't know why I didn't think to try it. I'll accept the answer after the 10 minutes is up.